# Fill in Missing rows using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to fill in missing values.  A simple example is table A has 10 rows with Id's of 1 through 10.

Table B has 5 rows of 1,3,5,7,9

I need to use table A to fill in the missing even numbers from Table B.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Is this Microsoft SQL Server? Have you tried an updated statement? If so, can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #A (
    Id INT
    ,Val VARCHAR(10)
    )

CREATE TABLE #B (
    Id INT
    ,Val VARCHAR(10)
    )

INSERT INTO #A (
    Id
    ,Val
    )
VALUES (
    1
    ,'1'
    )

INSERT INTO #A (
    Id
    ,Val
    )
VALUES (
    2
    ,'2'
    )

INSERT INTO #A (
    Id
    ,Val
    )
VALUES (
    3
    ,'3'
    )

INSERT INTO #B (
    Id
    ,Val
    )
VALUES (
    1
    ,'1'
    )

INSERT INTO #B (
    Id
    ,Val
    )

SELECT Id
    ,Val
FROM #A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM #B b
        WHERE b.Id = a.Id
        )
        AND a.Id % 2 = 0

Select * from #B
```

Comment: Ok I think I simplified this too much, so here is an example.  I am not using ID's, its more of a text field I am searching.  I have a whole list of distinct values in a varchar field as Table B.  In table A I have two fields.  One is Month and the other is the same text field as Table B.  For each month I want to compare Table A to B and pull in the missing values.  The result will be that each month has the exact same amount of rows that were filled in from Table B.

Comment: @BenW update your question with the table examples, and expected output that way we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Run a select query towards table A with a for loop that compares I’d for each loop. If I’d don’t match execute an insert. If you want to run it inside DB make an SP for it otherwise create a simple console app or such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT...`

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT B.ID FROM B 
WHERE B.ID % 2 = 0
AND B.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM A)
```

Just make sure to `SELECT` the same columns that you are inserting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `not exists` like below :

```
insert into B
select ID from A 
where ID % 2 = 0 and not exists(select 1 from B where ID = A.ID)
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9d87b/1)